# Suppose that $f$ is convergence preserving, then show that for some open neighbourhood of $0$, $f$ is antisymmetric w.r.t. the $y$ axis.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, real-numbers

> Suppose that $f: \mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ is a function(may not be continuous) such that for any converging series $\Sigma^{\infty}_{n=1}a_n$, $f(\Sigma^{\infty}_{n=1})$ is also a converging series. Show that there is some open ball of $0$, such that for any $x$ in this open ball, $f(-x)=-f(x)$.

If $f$ is linear, then clearly, for any converging series, $\Sigma^{\infty}_{n=1}a_n$, the series $\Sigma^{\infty}_{n=1}f(a_n)=f(\Sigma^{\infty}_{n=1}a_n)$ surely converges. And of course, the function is antisymmetric on the entire real line.

Let show the claim by assuming the opposite is true, namely: Suppose that for ever open ball $O$, there is some $x\in O$ such that $f(-x)\neq -f(x)$. Then let's show that there is a converging series $\Sigma^{\infty}_{n=1}a_n$ such that $\Sigma^{\infty}_{n=1}f(a_n)$ diverges. It comes naturally to one that we can first of choose any sequence of open balls centered at $0$, such that the interval becomes smaller and smaller as $n$ goes to infinity. And for each open ball, choose a number $x$ such that $f(-x)=-f(x)$ as the value of the sequence at $n$. Such sequence converges to $0$, therefore it's possible that summing all the terms in the sequence gives out a finite value. However, I don't see if this is going to help in any way.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $f$ is indeed convergence preserving.

First, it is clear that $f(x)\to0$ when $x\to0$, for if $x_n\to0$ with $|f(x_n)|>\varepsilon>0$ then some subsequence of $(x_n)$ will be absolutely summable, but no subsequence of $(f(x_n))$ can be summable.

So now assume $x_n\to0$ with $f(-x_n)\ne-f(x_n)$.

Note that $\sum_n t_n$ converges if $t_n\to0$ and  $t_{2k-1}=-t_{2k}$ for all $k$. Construct such a series where each term is $\pm x_n$, say $t_{2k}=\pm x_{n_k}$, where $(n_k)$ is non-decreasing and $n_k\to\infty$.

Pick the signs so that $f(t_{2k-1})+f(t_{2k})$ (which is nonzero by assumption and construction) always has the same sign, and repeat these pairs if necessary enough time to ensure that $\sum_n f(t_n)=\pm\infty$.

Comment: How do you make sure that we can find a subsequence of $x_n$, $x_{n_k}$, such that the sequence $f(x_{n_k})+f(-x_{n_k})$ doesn't sign? Also, $f(t_{2k-1}+f(t_{2k}))$ always have the same sign doesn't mean that $\Sigma_n f(t_n)$ diverges, for example $\frac 1{2^n}$

Comment: For the first one, if you have a sequence of nonzero numbers then either infinitely many are positive, or infinitely many are negative. For the second one, you're right, but you can repeat those two terms as often as you wish (but only a finite number of times, of course), to make the sum bigger than $1$, say.